# Best way to group string members of object in a vector

Tags: c++, string, sorting, object, vector

I am trying to store a vector of objects and sort them by a string member possessed by each object. It doesn't need to be sorted alphabetically, it only needs to group every object with an identical string together in the vector.

IE reading through the vector and outputting the strings from beginning to end should return something like:

```
string_bulletSprite
string_bulletSprite
string_bulletSprite
string_playerSprite
string_enemySprite
string_enemySprite
```

But should NEVER return something like:

```
string_bulletSprite
string_playerSprite
string_bulletSprite
[etc.]
```

Currently I am using std:sort and a custom comparison function:

```
std::vector<GameObject*> worldVector;
```

[...]

```
std::sort(worldVector.begin(), worldVector.end(), compString);
```

And the comparison function used in the std::sort looks like this:

```
bool compString(GameObject* a, GameObject* b)
{
    return a->getSpriteNameAndPath() < b->getSpriteNameAndPath();
}
```

getSpriteNameAndPath() is a simple accessor which returns a normal string.

This *seems* to work fine. I've stress tested this a fair bit and it seems to always group things together the way I wanted.

My question is, is this the ideal or most logical/efficient way of accomplishing the stated goal? I get the impression Sort isn't quite meant to be used this way and I'm wondering if there's a better way to do this if all I want to do is group but don't care about doing so in alphabetic order.

Or is this fine?

Comment: *"I get the impression Sort isn't quite meant to be used this way"* - If that were the case, `std::sort` would never provide a way to override the default comparator, `std::less<T>`, with one more appropriate to your requirements. So long as your comparator provides a strict weak ordering across your data domain, it's fine. That said, consider a functor or lambda, which stand a higher chance of inlining, and the latter can be done entirely local to the point-of-sort.

Comment: "So long as your comparator provides a strict weak ordering across your data domain" I was having some problems initially because I used != or == with the comparison function, but then it was pointed out that std:sort wants use of the < operator, and it was fine with that change. "That said, consider a functor or lambda, which stand a higher chance of inlining, and the latter can be done entirely local to the point-of-sort" I admit I'm something of a newcomer and this is my first "serious" project like this. So I'm not familliar with functor/lambda or inlining meaning.

Comment: Some [good reading on what a functor is](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/pointers-to-members#functor-vs-functionoid). A [lambda](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) is groovy syntactic sugar that compiles to a functor. The compiler has an easier time seeing that the code in the functor can be optimised right into the code using the functor for what is often significant performance advantages.. Instead of calling a function, you could wind up with code that inserts, inlines, the functor's comparison logic right into the sort algorithm.

Comment: An alternative: `std::unordered_map<std::string, std::vector<your_object_type> >`.  Use the object's string member as the key for the map, where there's a vector of all the objects with identical strings.  Upside: avoids sorting.  Downside: You need two loops to iterate over all objects.

Comment: Okay so reading up a bit on functor and lambda. So if I'm understanding it correctly, a functor in this case would simply be turning the sort function into its own class, while a lambda would be to essentially write the function RIGHT inside the sorts third argument? And that either of these would improve performance / efficiency?

Comment: Mostly: Two small clarifications: the function becomes the `operator()` of the class and you don't *have* to write the lambda inside the sort function call, but that's often the best place for it. If you have a massive lambda that would clutter things up, move the lambda. And consider not using a lambda because (opinion) lambdas are best kept short and sweet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like Functor or Lambda is the way to go for this particular program, but I realized some time after posting that I could just create an ID for the images and sort those instead of strings. Thanks for the help though, everyone!

Answer (score 1):

If you have lots of equivalent elements in your range, then `std::sort` is less efficient than manually sorting the elements.

You can do this by shifting the minimum elements to the beginning of the range, and then repeating this process on the remaining non-minimum elements

```
// given some range v

auto b = std::begin(v);  // keeps track of remaining elements
    
while (b != std::end(v))  // while there's elements to be arranged
{
    auto min = *std::min_element(b, std::end(v));  // find the minimum

    // move elements matching that to the front
    // and simultaneously update the remaining range
    b = std::partition(b, std::end(v), 
                       [=](auto const & i) {
                           return i == min;
                       });
}
```

Of course, a custom comparator can be passed to `min_element`, and the lambda in `partition` can be modified if equivalence is defined some other way.

Note that if you have very few equivalent elements, this method is much less efficient than using `std::sort`.

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/ef4zx4o4h) with a range of ints.

Comment: Thank you for the great example. I'm actually not sure at this stage how many equivalencies there will be. I think there's either going to be a LOT, or almost none. But I'll definitely keep this in mind.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understood your question correctly, if so, I will give you a little example of `std::map` which is great for grouping things by keys, which will most probably be a `std::string`.

Please take a look:

```
class Sprite
{
public:
    Sprite(/* args */)
    {
    }

    ~Sprite()
    {
    }
};

int main(int argc, char ** argv){

    std::map <std::string, std::map<std::string, Sprite>> sprites;
    std::map <std::string, Sprite> spaceships;
    spaceships.insert(std::make_pair("executor", Sprite()));
    spaceships.insert(std::make_pair("millennium Falcon", Sprite()));
    spaceships.insert(std::make_pair("death star", Sprite()));
    sprites.insert(std::make_pair("spaceships",spaceships)); 

    std::cout << sprites["spaceships"]["executor"].~member_variable_or_function~() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the great example! I'm thinking I want to stick with using Vectors instead of Maps, but this could work for sorting sprites by themselves.